# Are pulse shaping and windowing functions the same in concept?

Tags: digital-communications

I read a digital communication problem and they interchange terms as windowing function and pulse shaping and refer to it as same entity. For example the following windowing function with Transition time $T_R$ used to smooth transitions between symbols is also refered to as pulse shaping

$w_T(t)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}(0.5+\frac{t}{T_{TR}})) & \mbox{if $-T_{TR}/2 < t<T_{RT}/2$};\\
        1 & \mbox{if $T_{TR}/2 < t<T-T_{TR}/2$}\\
 \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}(0.5-\frac{t-T}{T_{TR}})) & \mbox{if $T-T_{TR}/2 < t<T+T_{TR}/2$};\\
\end{array} \right. $

My understanding is that a pulse shaping function limits signal bandwidth to transmission bandwidth.

How come the two are refered to as same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowing and pulse shaping are very similar, and are implemented in similar ways, but their purposes are different.

- Windowing means multiplying a discrete signal by a pulse with certain spectral properties before calculating its Fourier transform. The purpose is reducing the effect of discontinuities at both ends of the discrete signal.
- In QAM and related digital signals, the information is transmitted in the amplitudes of a sequence of pulses. Pulse shaping means choosing a pulse with the desired spectral and orthogonality properties.

Note that some digital communications textbooks assume (many times implicitly) a rectangular pulse shape, which is then converted to another pulse shape (using a filter, as in the example in your question). In my opinion, this formulation is unncecessarily complex -- it is better to explicity select  a pulse shape from the start.

Note also that pulse shaping may be understood as the convolution of a stream of deltas with a pulse shape; in that sense, pulse shaping is a sort of "dual" of windowing.

Comment: Thanks MBaz but I have question. So in your opinion does this windowing function I provided here also performs pulse shaping?

Comment: Yes. It's a matter of context. You can multiply $w_T(t)$ by a sequence before calculating its FT (windowing). Or you can use it as a filter to shape (in time and frequency) a digital communications signal (pulse shaping).

Comment: Actually this function $W_T(t)$ in the application I saw is being used after the IFFT operation for an OFDM symbol  before transmission over the bandwidth.

Comment: It is used for pulse shaping, then.

Comment: Concerning your last statement, couldn't it be a bit confusing to refer to pulse shaping as "windowing a stream of time-shifted discrete deltas"? Because in that case the two signals are convolved, whereas normally windowing refers to multiplication (in the time domain).

Comment: @MattL. On second reading, I agree with you, it is confusing. What I meant is that the spectrum of each delta is made to "conform to" the spectrum of the pulse. I have edited my answer. If it's still confusing, please let me know.

Comment: @Henry In OFDM, the pulse shape of all subcarriers is implicitly rectangular due to the usage of the IDFT. Windowing of the IDFT output signal is usually applied to shape the spectrum of the transmit singal as a whole. The term "windowing" is used in order to not confuse it with the ususal concept of "the convolution of a stream of deltas with a pulse shape" as MBaz has nicely described pulse shaping.

Comment: @Mbaz thank you it is clear in your answer

Comment: @Deve do you mean the whole OFDM symbol has a retangular time domain pulse shape?

Comment: @Deve one more comment regardimg the fact that the output after IDFT is a rectangular pulse would mean that the frequrncy domain is sinc function? in this case I dont understand why we need to shape the spectrum.

Comment: @Henry All you say is correct: every subcarrier as well as the complete OFDM symbol effectively has a rectangular pulse shape. This results in a sinc-like spectrum *per subcarrier*. A sinc function has an infinite bandwidth, theoretically. Windowing tries to reduce the bandwidth and to make the OFDM spectrum decline faster at its edges.